# Rails 4 collection_select ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to order my collection_select dropdown by name instead of the default ID.

I have searched for a way to do this in Rails 4 but haven't found the solution. My code is:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:material_id, Material.order('name ASC').all, :id, :name) %>
```

This still returns a list ordered by ID. The models I'm using are:

Glaze.rb
    has_many :ingredients
    has_many :materials, :through => :ingredients

Ingredients.rb
    belongs_to :glaze
    belongs_to :material
Material.rb
    has_many :ingredients
    has_many :glazes, :through => :ingredients

Comment: `<%= f.select :material_id, Material.order('name ASC').map {|c| c.name }, {prompt:"Choose Material"}, class: "form-control" %>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, It should work. Will be passed `name` and attribute value with `c.id`

```
<%= f.select :material_id, Material.order('name ASC').map {|c| [c.name, c.id] }, 
                           {prompt:"Choose Material"}, class: "form-control" %>
```